# How to write ,,friendship” in Chinese

Tags: translation, grammar

Me and my bestfriend are going to get a tattoo and I'd like to know how to really spell friendship in Chinese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"友谊 - friendship"

You may also request "友情" for the tattoo, which means "friendly feelings/comradeliness/good-fellowship" between the two of you.

Comment: In my view, though both have the base meaning of "friendship", 友情 is more suitable for close, personal friends, whereas 友谊 is for friendship in general?

Comment: @WayneCheah Quite agree.